# Degree of freedom in ideal and real case

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

what will be the degree of freedom of a massless rod, moving freely in space with a particle which is constrained to move on it? What is meaning of massless rod?

Comment: massless rod is an ideal case,so massless rod should be treated as a 1D line or a rigid body with mass tending to zero or something with 0 degree of freedom(like string is treated in simple pendulum).

Comment: A massless rod has zero degree of freedom, a particle that move on it has 1 degree of freedom

Comment: But answer mentioned in book is 4